# Dynamic FormArray with input fields has input blocked

Tags: typescript, angular6, formarray

I'm trying to dynamically create a FormArray in angular6 in combination with bootstrap.

My HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <mat-dialog-content>
        <div id="arrayDisplay">
            <button mat-button id="dialog-addEntry-button" class="btn blue"  type="button" (click)="addItem()">
                Add new entry
            </button>
            <div formArrayName="fooBar" *ngFor="let item of form.controls.fooBar?.value; let i = index;">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <input formControlName="foo" required  placeholder="foo">
                    <input formControlName="bar" required  placeholder="bar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button id="dialog-submit-button" class="btn blue" type="submit" 
                [disabled]="form.invalid || form.pending || form.pristine">
            Accept
        </button>
        <button mat-button id="dialog-cancel-button" class="btn grey-salsa btn-outline" type="button" mat-dialog-close>
            Cancel
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

My Typescript is as follows:

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ShzizzleNizzle implements OnInit{

    public form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)
    {

    }

    createItem(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            foo: 'test',
            bar: ''
        });
    }

    addItem(): void {
        const myShizzle = this.form.controls.fooBar as FormArray
        myShizzle.push(this.createItem());
    }


    submit(): void {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.form.controls.transactionData.value));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
        fooBar: this.fb.array([])});
    }
}
```

When i execute this code, i can add entries to the array, but I cannot enter values into the fields foo and bar. What am I doing wrong? Or is the issue elsewhere? Like the webpack build for example.

I have used these links as guidelines to create this form:
[tektutorials](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms/)
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
[netbasal](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)

EDIT: if i rename the formArrayName, i can input values, but they do not require validations

Comment: Without a fiddler it's hard to see, but the fact that each item in your HTML gets the same name and formControlName looks a bit off. You seem to be doing it a bit differently to the example on tektutorials. Wouldn't it be better to give them unique names?

Comment: I tried removing those, but no success. I think it's a form naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the array HTML to this:

```
<div formArrayName="fooBar" *ngFor="let item of getFooBar().controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="foo" required  placeholder="foo">
        <input formControlName="bar" required  placeholder="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

and adding this function to typescript

```
getFooBar(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("fooBar") as FormArray
}
```